# Hide dropdown on clickaway VueJS

Tags: vuejs2

I have a dropdown menu that has `position: absolute;` I need it so when the user clicks away from the dropdown it will close.

I simply have a `showDropdown` data attribute which is either true or false. Clicking on the button is: `@click="showDropdown = !showDropdown"` which all works perfectly.

I am using the `vue-clickaway` mixin however can't figure out how to hide it only when it's open.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Using vue-clickaway I used the below code:

```
dropdownClickAway(e) {
    if(this.showDropdown && e.target != this.$refs.dropdownButton) this.showDropdown = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have to methods to toggle the dropdown.

One for toggling the Dropdown.

```
toggleDropdown () {
    this.showDropdown = ! this.showDropdown
}
```

And one for hiding the dropdown.

```
hideDropdown () {
    this.showDropdown = false
}
```

And use it on bind events ( for `@click` and `v-on-clickaway` ) like so:

```
<button class="dropdown-toggle" @click="toggleDropdown"> . . . </button>
// And
<div class="dropdown" v-show="showDropdown" v-on-clickaway="hideDropdown"> . . . </div>
```

Comment: I think the `v-on-clickaway` property should be on the button which has the click activation method. Either way, this will work well if you are using the npm package vue-clickaway.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually more of a CSS question than a Vue question, but you can basically do the following:

```
// component
<div class="dropdown" :class="{ 'is-open': showDropdown }">
  // elements
  <button @click="showDropdown = !showDropdown">Close Dropdown</button>
</div>

// css
.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  // other styles
}

.dropdown.is-open {
  display: block;
}
```

This line: `:class="{ 'is-open': showDropdown }"` applies the `is-open` class whenever `showDropdown === true`. The `display` properties basically show/hide the menu whether the `is-open` class is present or not. You could change these styles to give a more stylish animation using css transitions, but that's the general premise.